# Fatal:invalid genesis file:hex string has length 2, want 64 for common.hash

Tags: blockchain, genesis

I'm new on the website. I'm following a french tutorial (yes i'm french) to create my own blockchain network. After installing all Geth stuff, creating my genesis file as following :

> {
>    "nonce": "0x00",
>    "difficulty": "0x1000",
>    "mixHash": "0x00",
>    "timestamp": "0x00",
>    "parentHash": "0x00",
>    "extraData": "0x00",
>    "gasLimit": "0x1000000000"
>    }

Then I tiped the following line :

> sudo geth --datadir ./noeud1 --networkid "100" init genesis.json

I have the following error :

> Fatal:invalid genesis file: hex string has length 2, want 64 for common.hash

Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

Copy the follwing code in your genesis.json file

```
{
 "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
 "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "difficulty": "0x400",
 "alloc": {},
 "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "timestamp": "0x00",
 "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
 "extraData": "0x",
 "gasLimit": "0xffffffff",
 "config": {
    "chainId": 59,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
 }
}
```

You can put your own chainid , not 1,2,3 they are Reserved

then run the command

```
geth --datadir ~ / yourDataDirectory  init genesis.json
```

or Follow this tutorial, its very helpful.
[Chainskills](http://chainskills.com/2017/03/10/part-3-setup-the-private-chain-miners/)

Comment: Thank you mate it was very helpful. I will follow the tutorial ;)